# C2DM: does Google enforce 1-to-1 between apps and sender accounts?

Tags: android, android-c2dm

When you sign up for C2DM with a Google account, you specify the name of the app package that you will be sending messages to. Question - if you want to send messages to several apps, do you have to register several times? Do they have to be distinct Google accounts? Or is the package name just there for logging/proof of good faith purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just there for proof of good faith. I changed the package name of one of my apps a few times and it didn't affect the C2DM delivery.

And, besides that, the package name isn't really a safe way to register your app to the C2DM service. Nobody hinders me in setting, for example, com.google.android.awesomeapp as my package name and setting this value in the C2DM registration.